# Mediaqueries for Macbook 2009 and Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1

Tags: android, ios, css, media-queries

I'm creating a responsive email template. And I've come across a problem.

I've written a mediaquery for the Samsung Galaxy Tab 2.0 10.1":

```
/* 10.1 inch Samsung Galaxy Tab (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen
    and (min-device-width : 800px)
    and (max-device-width : 1280px) {

        .tablethide{
            display: none;
        }

    .tablet_width{
        zoom: 1.8;
    }

}
```

But since the Samsung tablet and the MacBook share the same resolution, the zoom will aply on the mackbook also.

So I have to put something else in the mediaquery to distinguish the tablet from the Macbook.

Has anyone an idea of how I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Solved it myself by changing the viewport

Answer (score 0):

Hey Was having the same problems I found that the resolution of the Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 is actually (max-width: 2560px) and (orientation: landscape) or (max-width: 1600px) and (orientation: portrait)